# Unable to take 2 inputs simultaneously

Tags: haskell, getline

I'm a haskell beginner. My code:

```
module Main (main) where

import System.IO

--Type for identifying Students.
data Student = Student {
        name :: String,
        regnum :: Integer
    }   deriving (Show, Read)

getData :: IO (String)
getData = do
    putStr "\tEnter the student's name: "
    name <- getLine
    putStr "\tEnter the registration number: "
    regstr <- getLine
    let regno = (read regstr) :: Integer
    return (show ( Student name regno ))

addData :: String -> IO (Bool)
addData filename = do
    fileData <- getData
    appendFile filename fileData
    return True

printData :: String -> IO (Bool)
printData filename = do
    fileData <- readFile filename
    putStrLn fileData
    return True

resetFile :: String -> IO (Bool)
resetFile filename = writeFile filename "" >> return True

action :: Char -> String -> IO (Bool)
action option filename =
    if option == '1'
        then addData filename
    else if option == '2'
        then printData filename
    else if option == '3'
        then resetFile filename
    else return False

main = do 
        putStr "What do you want to do?\n\t1) Add a new record to a file.\n\t2) Read a record from a file.\n\t3) Reset the file.\n>> "
        option <- getChar
        action option "records.txt"
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
What do you want to do?
    1) Add a new record to a file.
    2) Read a record from a file.
    3) Reset the file.
>> 1
    Enter the student's name:   Enter the registration number:
```

Hence I'm unable to provide input to for the student's name. I'm running the code on **ghci**. When I tried to see how it runs as an executable it gave a even weirder output.

```
What do you want to do?
    1) Add a new record to a file.
    2) Read a record from a file.
    3) Reset the file.
```

(Notice it doesn't print ">>"). Only after I press Enter twice does it print ">>".
I can't understand whats happening here. Other improvements to my code are very welcome.

---

EDIT:: By using getLine instead of getChar , the program works on ghci(thanks to Daniel Fischer). But it still doesn't work when compiled. The new output is:

```
What do you want to do?
    1) Add a new record to a file.
    2) Read a record from a file.
    3) Reset the file.
1   (Typed my me)
Tom (Typed my me)
234 (Typed my me)
>> Enter the student's name: Enter the registration number:
```

On re-running to read the file:

```
What do you want to do?
    1) Add a new record to a file.
    2) Read a record from a file.
    3) Reset the file.
2   (Typed my me)
>> Student {name = "Tom", regnum = 234}
```

Why is ">>" and getData's `putStr`s being printed after taking the input?

Comment: Don't use `getChar` for getting interactive input, it doesn't work as expected. `hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering` may or may not help here because the terminal might do its own line buffering.

Comment: Now it's the buffered output (also line-buffered). Call `hFlush stdout` after each `putStr` that doesn't end with a newline. (See last part of my answer)

Comment: That does work, but its quite a hassle.

Comment: @Likhit I have a simplifying suggestion (define a function for that), and added a few remarks concerning the "Other improvements".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
option <- getChar
```

With the default buffering settings, the programme only receives the input after a newline has been entered. The `getChar`, however, removes only the first character entered from the input buffer, so the following `getLine` reads from the input buffer until it finds a newline. In your case, immediately at the beginning.

You can (at least on *nix-ish systems, buffering control used to not work properly on Windows, I don't know if it now does) solve the problem by turning off buffering for `stdin`,

```
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    ...
```

so the `getChar` receives the input without a newline being typed. Alternatively, instead of using `getChar` for the option, use

```
(option:_) <- getLine
```

so there doesn't remain anything in the input buffer to auto-satisfy the following `getLine`.

Also, to get the prompts printed out before the input is entered, call

```
hFlush stdout
```

to flush the output buffer, or turn off buffering for `stdout`.

Most simple is probably to define

```
prompt :: String -> IO ()
prompt msg = do
    putStr msg
    hFlush stdout
```

and replace the calls to `putStr` with calls to `prompt`.

---

Critique of coding style:

```
getData :: IO (String)
```

You enclose the arguments of the `IO` type constructor in parentheses. That's not necessary and unidiomatic. The normal way to write it is `IO String`. (You probably have the parentheses from seeing `IO ()` somewhere, but those are not parentheses enclosing no type, that's the type constructor for the `()` type. Confusing? Yes.)

```
action :: Char -> String -> IO (Bool)
action option filename =
    if option == '1'
        then addData filename
    else if option == '2'
        then printData filename
    else if option == '3'
        then resetFile filename
    else return False
```

That should become a `case`,

```
action option filename
    = case option of
        '1' -> addData filename
        '2' -> printData filename
        '3' -> resetFile filename
        _   -> return False
```

Apart from that, the code looks clean.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `(:_)` does in `(option:_)`. Is it an operator?

Comment: `so the getChar receives the input without a newline being typed` — no, this doesn't work (for me on Linux at least).

Comment: It's a pattern-match. `(:)` is a constructor of the list type, `_` is a wildcard pattern. So `(option : _) <- getLine` means "call getLine, bind option to the first character and ignore the rest".

Comment: @n.m. It does work, it just waits for the next input. The prompt "Enter the student's name" is not printed since the output is buffered. `hFlush`ing it, or setting the buffering of `stdout` to `NoBuffering` makes it work as intended (on Linux, at least).

Comment: `hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering` still doesn't work on windows.
While using `(option:_) <- getLine` works on ghci, it still doesn't work as an executable. I'm putting the new output as an edit in the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I really learnt a lot from this answer (for one I didn't realize that pattern matching could be used in simple statements. I thought only function parameters could be pattern matched.)

Comment: @Likhit You're welcome. But you can't pattern-match in any old expression, the match in `(option : _) <- getLine` becomes a pattern-match on a function argument after desugaring, since desugared it is `getLine >>= \(option : _) -> ...`. You can pattern-match in case-expressions and on function arguments.